# Updating Cartthrob Order Status on Entry Item Id Level

Tags: cartthrob, status, orders

I'm working on a site where the client needs to approve each order on the order_id level. They also need to be able to approve order items on the specific entry_id level as well. So if one item is not available for purchase, they can change the status of that item and still approve the order itself. For example, based on the image I've attached, the user would like to be able to look at this order and set a status for entry_id 24 to Approved and then set the status to Denied for entry_id 23.

Is there a way to do this in the backend of Cartthrob via the control panel using statuses?

Thank you for your time.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an easy way to accomplish this natively.

One thing you could try is saving a custom "status" item_option when adding to cart. Give it a value of "pending" or something similar.

The downside is you'd have to type the status in manually.

On the back end you could write a little add on that would replace the default order items input field with a select that has your statuses.

Comment: Thank you mjr. I appreciate your feedback. I may try creating a status item_option like you suggested and see how that goes.